# get error after add routing to my anglularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in angularjs and I want to load new content from another html file I use this below codes but I don't know why I get this errors

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector......
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("boors", ['ngRoute']);
app.config(boorsRouter);
function boorsRouter($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider
             .when('#/', {templateUrl: 'partials/news.html',
              controller: function  ($scope) {
                 $scope.setActive('news');
              }})
 ;
}
```

I add this script in html file

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

where I go wrong?

Comment: What does error message complain about?

Comment: I don't know exactly what does it about I don't know why i get that error

Comment: It's hard to say. There is some error. I think in the code you didn't include here.

Comment: when i remove the rout the error disapear

Comment: What is `$scope.setActive`?

Comment: you can include not minified `angular.js` and `angular-route.js` - it can help you get more readable error. can you provide full error text?

Answer (score 0):

Remove # in the when method.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/news.html',
        controller: function  ($scope) {
            $scope.setActive('news');
        }
    });
```

Comment: i remove all of the content of function but anything doesnt change

Comment: what is $scope.setActive()?

Comment: it is a function for display a content , I REMOVE ALL THE CONTENT OF FUNCTION